# Computer Randomly Powers Off. What's The Cause?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, power, overheating

I upgraded my computer a month or two ago now and now every so often, my computer will randomly shutdown (and then restart after about 5 seconds). To clarify, it usually shuts down when coming out of sleep mode, it did it while I was downloading an update and also when booting into Windows. I upgraded the motherboard and CPU but I didn't replace the power supply or RAM. I read online to check the fuses on the motherboard to see if there's any corrosion and I don't see any.

I've contacted the motherboard manufacturer (MSI) and they said to try reinstalling Windows, reset BIOS, test the power supply on another PC, or replace the power supply. I reinstalled Windows, reset the BIOS to the default settings and I also moved the plug (for the power supply) to another surge protector but that didn't fix it. I also thought it might be the CPU overheating so I replaced the heatsink but that didn't fix it either.

I was looking at getting a power supply tester but I'm wondering if it's worth spending $20 on or if I should just buy a new power supply? I'm thinking it's the power supply because it's 6+ years old now but it worked fine with the old motherboard and it's 500W (they advertise it as being 550W but that's only under heavy loads) which should be what I need for my setup. If it might be my CPU overheating, what is a good way to find that out? My old motherboard would beep if it overheated but I guess this motherboard doesn't do that.

Here's my specifications:

- Motherboard: MSI Z97-GD65 Gaming
- CPU: Intel Core i7 4790K
- PSU: Rocketfish 500W
- Graphics card: nVidia Geforce 9600 GT
- RAM: 1x8GB Patriot Memory 667 MHz (Part # PSD38G13332) and 3x2GB Mushkin 667 MHz (Part # 991772)
- Windows 8.1 (x64)

For the record, I have NOT overclocked my graphics card or CPU. I've made sure that all the drivers (including the BIOS firmware) is up to date. There's also no power supply voltage switch to change (that I can see).

I'm hoping it's not the motherboard because the warranty from the store is out and I can't wait 4-6 weeks for a new one from the manufacturer. Any ideas on what I can do to dig down and find the root of this problem?

Comment: PSU testers for $20 are worthless, they don't test it for max output, try a better PSU.

Comment: I wouldn't try upgrading the PSU just yet, before confirming that everything else is OK. How is your CPU cooling paste? This element is often overlooked, and has a huge impact on temperatures. Have you checked to ensure that your CPU temp is actually OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the other suggestions about the PSU may be going down the right path, but it's better not to just throw parts at something without doing some more troubleshooting.

I noticed that your new motherboard has onboard video. Did your old motherboard? I ask because the 9600GT (older card, so I assume you used it in your old system) requires 400W. The new board may be pulling more power, along with the upgraded CPU, and memory.

I would suggest turning off the onboard video in the BIOS to save on power consumption, along with any other features you aren't using.

Also, look in your event viewer and see if there are any errors there that might indicate why it's rebooting. You may also want to install some voltage monitoring software but if it only happens coming out of sleep that may not help.

But 500W is on the low side for a system with an external graphics card.

Comment: I went into BIOS and it looks like the integrated graphics card should be disabled automatically as the only setting for "Initiate Graphics Card" is PEG (PCIE Graphics?) or IDG (Integrated Graphics Device?). That setting is set to PEG. My old motherboard (ASUS P6T) didn't have an onboard graphics card. As for the Event Viewer, I've checked that a dozen times and the only error that pops out is ``The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.`` (which ``BugcheckCode`` is set to ``0``)

Comment: There's also an error in the event viewer saying ``The Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).`` but that is showing before or after the computer randomly shuts down. I think I'll just run to the store and buy a power supply. If it still does it, then I can always take it back.

Comment: It looks like a new (proper and reliable) power supply would be $200+ which I don't have right now so I tried a few different things. I opened the case, took out all the internal SATA, power and USB connectors and then put them back in. I took out the triple channel RAM chips and now there's just 1x8GB RAM chip in. There was also a screw that came out of no where when I turned the case on its side. I put the computer in and then out of sleep mode 5 times and it didn't shutdown. Now that could've just been luck so I'll have to wait and see if it does it again.

Comment: Hopefully that will hold you over until you can get a new PSU. I would highly recommend an [Ultra](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?MfrId=1583&CatId=106) when you get one.

Comment: Just an update, since I posted this question just over a week ago I haven't had one random shutdown and hopefully whatever it was, it's fixed (knock on wood). I also ordered a new PSU online as this Rocketfish one is old and is going to fail sooner or later.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem by my self. I read a little bit and found out that cheaper Power Supllies(don't know yours :-) ) had some fluctuation about 70 Watt. I had some amd dual core and an 8800 GT Overclocked. I bought a new Power Supply with 750 Watt and everything was fine. Your Graphic card is not the weakest, as it is your CPU. I would try a new cheap Powersuplly with 750 Watt or you buy an better one (e.g. be quiet) with 550W (as recommend by Intel).

He makes no Beeping noises while booting or the Motherboard Led is blinking odd. If it does take a look in your Motherboards Manual